# Change constructor precedence

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, overload-resolution

Is it possible to define a constructor for all derived types and a template constructor?
I've written this testcase to illustrate my problem:

```
#include <iostream>


class Variant;
class CustomVariant;


class Variant
{
public:
    Variant(void)
        {}


    Variant(const Variant&)
        {
            std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl;
        }


    Variant(const CustomVariant&)
        {
            std::cout << "custom" << std::endl;
        }


    template<typename T>
    Variant(const T&)
        {
            std::cout << "template" << std::endl;
        }
};


class CustomVariant : public Variant
{
};


class DerivedVariantA : public CustomVariant
{
};


class DerivedVariantB : public CustomVariant
{
};


int main(void)
{

    DerivedVariantB dvb;

    Variant v(dvb);
    // expcected output: "custom" instead of "template"

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
template <typename T> Variant(const T&)  // (a)
Variant(const CustomVariant&)            // (b)
```

No conversion is required to call **(a)**; the argument type, `DerivedVariantB`, is an exact match where `T = DerivedVariantB`.

A derived-to-base conversion is required to call **(b)**.  Therefore, **(a)** is a better match than **(b)**.

If you invoke the constructor with an argument of type `CustomVariant`, both constructors are exact matches, so **(b)** is selected because where everything else is equal, a nontemplate is preferred over a template.

You can suppress use of the template where `T` is derived from `Variant` by using `std::enable_if`:

```
template<typename T>
Variant(const T&, 
        typename std::enable_if<
                     !std::is_base_of<Variant, T>::value, void*
                 >::type = 0)
{
    std::cout << "template" << std::endl;
}
```

This makes the template not instantiable when `T` is derived from `Variant`, so it will not be available during overload resolution.  `enable_if` and `is_base_of` are new to C++ in C++0x and your compiler and standard library may support them.  If not, you can also find them in C++ TR1 or [Boost.TypeTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: Yeah, that are the rules defined by the standard. The question is, is there any workaround? :)

Comment: Wow great. That works because of SFINAE (value is not defined for types derived from Variant)?

Comment: @cytrinox: Yes, that's what SFINAE says and that's what `enable_if` is for.

Answer (score 0):

No, among the list of constructors available in the class there is no constructor that takes the instance of type `DerivedVariantB` as the argument. Hence the template generated is being called.

```
class DerivedVariantB ; // Forward Declaration

class Variant
{
    public:
    // ...

     Variant( const DerivedVariantB &obj )
     {
         std::cout << "\n DerivedVariantB \n";
     }
};
```

Now, it's possible to call the constructor that takes the reference of type `DerivedVariantB` instead of the template generated one.